# A state between two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two CSS classes (`c1` and `c2`), and I'm switching between them with CSS3 transitions.

Now, I want a div to **stay** (not animate) in a state between `c1` and `c2`, for example 60% `c1` and 40% `c2`. (If I play a transition with 1second duration between `c1` and `c2`, I want the state of frame that appears at 0.4s)

`c1` and `c2` has many properties (transforms, etc.), so it is not easy to calculate each property by required percents and set it to the `div`.

Is there any CSS/jQuery method for this purpose?

Comment: A lot of properties cannot be measured in percentages. So a general solution to this is very unlikely.

Comment: Browsers can calculate all of properties when they are playing a CSS3 animation. Isn't it possible to have the state of just one frame of that animation?

Comment: why not using a third class ? when the div is planned to be in this middle state ? on mouseout or what ?

Comment: No.  You'll need to write your own function to do this.  Animate is simply that - animate.

Comment: @reza I'm trying to implement swiping feature, so I need too many classes!

Comment: @Archer Do you mean animate function of jQuery? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, the jQuery animate function.  You could copy that from the jQuery source and modify it to make your own function, but you cannot do what you are asking with the existing function.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find `animate` function in jQuery source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js

Comment: maybe this discussion could help . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312289/interrupting-stop-a-css3-transition-on-the-actual-position-state

Comment: They took it out of jQuery 1.8 as part of its modularization process... see http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/22/jquery-1-8-beta-1-see-whats-coming-and-going

Answer (score 2):

jQueryUI's `switchClass`, `addClass` functions do not support the `step` function argument which makes achieving this really difficult.

However, if you can specify the styles in the animate code itself, this can be done - Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/fAZqn/2/

Answer (score 0):

[**Here is working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZdVk/17/), and here is structure:

**jQuery:**

```
//setting animation values
var value1 = 60;
var value2 = 40;

$('a').click(function(){
 var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
 //takes class from clicked element

 var selectEle = $('.'+ takeClass +'Box');
 //creating selector with takeClass value

 $('span').not(selectEle).animate({'width':value2+'px','height':value2+'px'},90);
 selectEle.animate({'width':value1+'px','height':value1+'px'},90);
});​
```

**html:**

```
<a class="c1">1</a>
<a class="c2">2</a>
<span class="c1Box"></span>
<span class="c2Box"></span>​
```