# How to stop CSS3 transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to stop a transition that is in progress.

I have found a few references[1][2] scattered around the internet but I can't seem to piece it together.

Here's a fiddle of the first suggestion (With jQuery and CSS Transit for context): http://jsfiddle.net/thomseddon/gLjuH/

Thanks

[1] https://twitter.com/evilhackerdude/status/20466821462

[2] github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/508

Comment: check this out maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312289/interrupting-stop-a-css3-transition-on-the-actual-position-state

Comment: Thanks, should have also linked to it

Comment: Got it: http://jsfiddle.net/thomseddon/gLjuH/3/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured it out: http://jsfiddle.net/thomseddon/gLjuH/3/

The trick is to set each css property you are animating to its current value (possibly mid transition) like: `$(this).css('prop', $(this).css('prop'));` (Probably would want to store all properties in an object in the element with $(this).data(props); and loop through them).

Once you have explicitly set the properties you can run a 0s animation to override the previous animation and effectively halt the element.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. I did some refactoring and broke it down to the core concept here: http://jsfiddle.net/jedhunsaker/gLjuH/13/

Comment: @mrjedmao - the fiddle link is dead :(

Comment: @Danield sorry, I changed my name recently so it's now http://jsfiddle.net/jedmao/gLjuH/13/

Comment: There is no need to do slice to cut the PX. parseInt do this automatic

Answer (score 6):

There's a much simpler solution. If you want to just stop the transition (and not pause it). Just set the css to current computed style. For example in a custom scrolling solution, where top is transitioned property.

```
element.style.top=getComputedStyle(element).top;
```

and that's it.