# How to replace a CSS3 transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to apply a CSS transition to an element, but at some point before it completes, remove the transition entirely and start another one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930098/how-to-stop-css3-transition) answers how to stop a transition in its tracks, but I modified the jsFiddle there to illustrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/zXVLd/

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.click(function(){
    $div.css({
        left: 0,
        transition: 'none'
    });
    $div.transit({
        top: 600,
    },5000);
});

function complete(){
    $div.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
}

$div.transit({left: 600}, 5000, 'linear', complete);
```

What I want to happen is for the box to reset its position and move down when clicked, and for the completed handler on the first transition to *not* fire.

What does happen is the box resets its position when clicked, but doesn't move down until the first transition completes (even though the motion from the first transition is no longer happening). The completed handler still fires on the first transition as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle with the `clearQueue` method: http://jsfiddle.net/zXVLd/1/

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.click(function(){
    $div.clearQueue().css('left', $div.css('left')).transit({
        top: 600,
    },5000);
});

function complete(){
    $div.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
}

$div.transit({left: 600}, 5000, 'linear', complete);
```

That does the trick. See http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ for more information on the clearQueue method.

Comment: The complete handler is still firing, but I might be able to work around that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of animations, you can try to use GSAP's TweenLite. It's incredible what you can achieve with it. http://www.greensock.com/jump-start-js/ If you include this on your page and add the following code:

```
    div.bind('click', function(e) {
    // note that you can animate two directions, from and to
    TweenLite.from(div /*element*/, 0.2 /*easing in seconds*/, {
        // the css, but for positioning elements you can also use x and y.
        x: 600,
        easing: linear,
        onStart: function() {
            Stuff you want to do before the animation
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            Stuff you want to do after animationg
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin which you use is using queue. So, it is just enough to call $div.dequeue(); I.e.

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.click(function(){
    $div.dequeue();
    $div.css({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        transition: 'none'
    });
    $div.transit({
        top: 600,
    },5000);
});

function complete(){
    $div.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
}

$div.transit({left: 600}, 5000, 'linear', complete);
```

fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/zXVLd/2/