# Is there a way to pause CSS transition mid-way?

Tags: javascript, css

Actually the subject is pretty explanatory. But to clarify, I am curious of several things:

1. Is there a way - not to disable - but to pause the property transition? (And then - resume it, perhaps).
2. Is there a way to read property change (by JavaScript) while it's in transition?
   For instance, will an `$(el).height()` return 50 after .5 seconds after the hover event, if the styles for el are: `el { height: 100px; transition: height 1s; }` and `el:hover { height: 0px; }` (it's a sketch, please pardon my syntax).

Comment: You can with JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312289/interrupting-stop-a-css3-transition-on-the-actual-position-state

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, thank you! I guess I'll take a second look when I've slept a bit. Now it doesn't seem so clear to me as to what your plugin does. jsFiddle seems to be static.

Comment: @Andrevinsky could you please reconsider your accepted answer. It does not answer this question at all! If you found a solution elsewhere, consider writing your own answer for the benefit of others! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Billy, in fact it does, too. Animation in CSS is performed with either `animation` rule or `transition` rule. If `animation` is used, then pausing is performed best with `animation-play-state:paused`. If `transition` is used, the best way would be to read transitioned property value and reapply it, effectively setting the end value and finishing transition. So, kudos to @Abraham P, still. He did answer my questions. If you object to my judgement, please explain your reasoning below. I will appreciate it.

Comment: @Andrevinsky Check the comments on the answer. In short, The question asks if there is a way to pause a CSS transition. The answer suggests that you use `animation-play-state: paused`, but this will not pause a CSS transition.

Comment: @Billy, yes. Correct. His answer need have been such:

1. You can only stop it, not pause. To do it, you need to read the current property value and assign it back.
2. Yes, you can read current style value.

(3.) Pausing is only available for animation.

But the answer he gave just sufficed for me. That's why I signed it off as a solution.

Comment: @Andrevinsky His answer does not state anything about re-assigning the style in order to pause the animation. To me, this case is simple; the question asks "Is there a way to pause a CSS transition". The answer does not provide an answer to this question whatsoever. Furthermore, (to your point no.3) he claims that you *can* use `animation-play-state` when in fact, you can not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use the `animation-play-state` CSS attribute, and toggle between

`animation-play-state:running`, and `animation-play-state:paused`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

2) The short answer is yes. Whichever property you read halfway through your transition (lets say `height`), will return the current value at the moment queried.

Comment: He's asking about transitions, not about animations.

Comment: What do you mean by "reading"? `.clientHeight`, `.style.height`, or `getComputedStyle().height`?

Comment: Nope, the `.style` declaration does always have the assigned value (or even none at all). See http://jsfiddle.net/MGGwL/

Comment: The animation-play-state property doesn't appear to control a running transition, only a running animation.

Comment: I really cant see why this is the accepted answer for this question.
animation-play-state does control a running animation but it doesnt affect a running transition.
So basically this answer is exactly not what youre searching for hitting this question.

Comment: @PHPMaster5000, I edited the reply in a way that might help the people seeking the solution to the initial problem: pausing the animated element (and perhaps, resuming it).