# Pause css transition on before element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to pause a css transition and found a similar question with a correct answer: [Is there a way to pause CSS transition mid-way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216060/is-there-a-way-to-pause-css-transition-mid-way)

But i could not get it to work on my code. I think the problem is the before element.

What am i doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.start_timer_1').click(function() {
    $('.timer_1').addClass('start');
  });
  $('.pause_timer_1').click(function() {
    $('.timer_1').toggleClass('pause');
  });
});
```

```css
.timer_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #efdfe1;
}
.timer_1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  background: #dc281e;
}
.timer_1.start.pause:before {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.timer_1.start:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 10000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: width 10000ms linear;
  -o-transition: width 10000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: width 10000ms linear;
  transition: width 10000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer_1"></div>
<button class="start_timer_1">Start</button>
<button class="pause_timer_1">Pause</button>
```

Here you can test the code: http://codepen.io/atticweb/pen/bdjPGj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right your problem here is you are trying to pause an `animation` when you have a `transition` (Auto tween animation).

So instead of transition you want:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes example {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.timer_1.start:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

also you don't need that many vendor prefixes for `transition` and `animations` you only need `-webkit-`.

Comment: Very nice answer! So transition does not work the same as animation, got it! I was hoping it could be done with only a simple transition, it's less code. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah a transition can only go from A to B (and don't actually change the property values so there is nothing to stop at.) where as an animation can have multiple phases' known as key-frames (which does change the property of your rule)and this is what able's you to pause it.